# Unknown error XAML

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xaml

Just started learning WP7 platform. Don't even know how to describe occurred error. It happens all the time when I'm creating new project (`Silverlight for Windows Phone` project).

```
System.Exception
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size     availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single    inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

[image]

Comment: Three questions: 1. Are you able to start up the emulator? 2. Are you able to start up Windows Media player? 3. Do you have Silverlight 4 installed?

Comment: Also, visual XAML editor works just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installing Windows solved this mysterious problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to this info on [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557132/catastrophic-failure-exception-from-hresult-0x8000ffff-e-unexpected-in-vs2010-express-blend-4-and-vs-2010-ultimate) (see the "Workaround" tab), a possible workaround is to reinstall the Windows Phone tools.

Answer (score 0):

re-installing vs2010 SP1 has worked wonders for weird issues i was having.. Worth a try.

Comment: actually, it didn't work for me. what worked, was re-installing windows. seriously.

Comment: funny i was almost going to put that as an addendum to my post but i would have avoided that at all costs (unless i was working in a VM of coarse :) )